# Converting date column to varchar column in Oracle with existing data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to change column type from DATE to VARCHAR2.  Currently, date column has so many records which are inserted previously and now I need to change column type from DATE to VARCHAR2 without losing any existing data. Please suggest me how can I do it?

Comment: what will be the benefit of this change rather than loosing type validity?

Comment: That is a really, really bad idea. Never, ever store date values as VARCHAR. Why would you want to do that? What is the real problem you are trying to solve with that really bad idea?

Comment: No, you don't need to change this - believe me. What is your real problem? If you have problems with time zones then either convert all times to UTC or use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

Answer (score 0):

simple demostration:

```
create table t (c date);
insert into t values (sysdate);

alter table t add c_tmp varchar2(20);
update t set c_tmp = c;
alter table t drop column c;
alter table t rename column c_tmp to c;

drop table t;
```

however, I don't recommend for most of the circumstances to convert data type from date to varchar2. It does not provide clear benefit on my point of view.

Comment: Thank you Dervis for your response, actually due to client-side(frontend UI date picker) time zone difference we are getting multiple issues with date, due to that we are trying to explore alternative ways

Comment: That's the worst you can do because you don't specify the format.

Comment: you will have way more problems if you store temporal data as strings, a date picker should do just that, choose a date, which might well be handled as a string through the UI, but the back-end needs dates (or timestamps)

Comment: @Kiran couldn't you add a virtual column that presents the date in some UI-friendly format, rather than throw away useful information?